# Plotting series of images using matplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to find an efficient way to draw an arbitrary number of images in a series inside a figure in Python using matplotlib.

This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

Each image will have a different width but the same height. Of course, we can use subplot but the problem with subplot images must have the same width plus the issue of spacing between different columns.

If I need to use another library/package to achieve that that is totally fine for me.

Notes:

1. The borders around each image should not exist but it is just for illustration.
2. I want to consider the figure as an area where I can plot images in any position and add text in a specific location.

Comment: you could define a custom grid with gridspec

Comment: You can use `plt.subplots(m,n)` where you need to plt **m*n** images

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gridspec` and specifying `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top`, `width_ratios` and `height_ratios` to generate subplots in a very flexible way. Pls see [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) for details.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
nrows=2
ncols=2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7.2, 7.2))

gs = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, left=0.1, right=0.6, bottom=0.55, top=0.95, width_ratios=[1, 2], height_ratios=[1, 1])

axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[row, col]) for row in range(nrows) for col in range(ncols)]
```